# 4N25 optocoupler drive solenoid

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

[image]

I am trying to drive solenoid using above circuit but its not working with IRF540 mosfet.
Can anyone help me the what is wrong with above circuit.

Thanks,

Comment: "not working", can you be any more unspecific?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening? 
What device do you use as input to the optocoupler?

Comment: What's not working? Is that your exact circuit, except with a solenoid instead of the bulb? Did it work once to energise the coil and not again?

Comment: What does the gate voltage do? ARe you sure the MOSFET is not wired backwards?

Comment: MOSFET is not wired backwards.

Comment: Measure the gate voltage (across the 10K resistor)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the reverse diode across the coil.  The lack of one probably caused the FET to get fried the first time you turned off the coil.

Add the diode, replace the FET, and try again.

Comment: That could also have fried the 4N25.

Comment: I have replaced the FET and add the diode. Solenoid energize always whether turn off or on 4N25.

Comment: Input of optocoupler from ULN2803 and atmega32 drives ULN2803.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem If you had drain and source swapped on the fet it would always energise the coil, are you sure that you wired it correctly?

Comment: I have checked now. Its correct connection. I have tried with 10K, 100k and 1M GS resistors.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem what does your meter tell you?